# extracting attachments from mail that is coming to my postfix inbox

Tags: email, postfix, fetchmail

How do I extract attachments from mails arriving at my postfix mailbox and preferably send the content of the attachment to another email account? I am interested in being able to acquire/read the content of the attachment on ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `procmail` if not already installed. In your postfix configuration ( `/etc/postfix/main.cf` ) make sure you have a line:

```
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
```

in your `~/.procmailrc` insert the following (you will need a different matching pattern):

```
:0
* ^Subject:.*some_text_to_match
| /usr/local/bin/your_processing_program
```

In `your_processing_program` extract the attachments and forward them e.g. with a python or ruby program.

How to display the attachments in terminal depends on the attachment content. If it is text you could write it to the end of a file and use `tail -f` in the terminal.