# Mail processing with custom script on Postfix and Plesk (plesk_virtual)

Tags: postfix, filter, plesk

I'd like to parse incoming mail with custom script. Something which would be easily done with
[man aliases(5)](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) for real users or with [`procmail`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145771/mail-filtering-with-procmail-in-a-postfix-dovecot-system-with-virtual-users/148095#148095) [for vitual users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79046/extracting-attachments-from-mail-that-is-coming-to-my-postfix-inbox).

But on my system is is `plesk` and setup is: `virtual_transport = plesk_virtual`, thus I cannot put configure it as `virtual_transport = procmail`.

What is `plesk_virtual` anyway, where are the configuration files, documentation? (`"plesk_virtual" site:https://docs.plesk.com/` finds nothing, [Mail doc](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/advanced-administration-guide-linux/services-management/mail-service.68762/) neither).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, at least I've found that `plesk_virtual` is an external delivery method, defined in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
plesk_virtual unix - n n - - pipe flags=DORhu user=popuser:popuser
argv=/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/postfix-local -f ${sender} -d ${recipient} -p
/var/qmail/mailnames
```

Thus it's a binary `/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/postfix-local`.

[source](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-users/2014-March/076318.html), [graph](https://kb.parallels.com/Attachments/kcs-15646/MTA_presentation.pdf) on page 3